# How to interpret inverse of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

I am new to linear algebra, and I am trying to interpret the inverse of a matrix.

If I have the equation $Ax = y$ and I solve for $x$ as $x = A^{-1}b$, plugging $x$ back in as $Ax$ results in either $Ax = y$ or $Ax \neq y$. How should I interpret this? It seems like the inverse gives the correct answer sometimes and sometimes doesn't without any warning.

In regular algebra if I am able to solve $ax = y$ for $x$, $ax = y$ is always true. Is there anyway of knowing whether my resulting $x$ will give me the right answer in advance, without explicitly checking the result of $Ax$ against my original $y$? I thought the inverse operation is supposed to give you back the original input, but inverse matrix multiplication seems strangely inconsistent.

Comment: If the inverse exists, then matrix algebra is just like normal algebra, in that plugging back $x$ as you’ve defined it into the equation $Ax=b$ will yield $b=b$.

Comment: "*plugging $x$ back in*"... I don't understand what you are doing here...  assuming that $A$ is invertible and that $Ax=y$, then you have $x = A^{-1}y$ and you have $A(A^{-1}y) = y$, similarly $A(A^{-1}x) = x$ and you have that $AA^{-1} = A^{-1}A = I$ is the identity matrix

Comment: Can you write an example of an $A$, $x$ and $y$ where this strange phenomenon ($Ax \neq y$ even when $x = A^{-1}y$ ) happened? As other commenters point out this should be impossible so we can't say more about what caused your example until you show it. It could be that you confused  $A^{-1}$ with a different matrix (e.g. $A^T$) or made a simple calculating error or discovered an inconsistency in mathematics itself. In either case I believe people here will be able to explain what's going on if you give the concrete matrices and vectors.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. For example $A = [1,0,1; 0,1 ,0 ], y = [1, 1, 1]$, Solve for $x$ such that $Ax = y$ vs $A = [1, 0, 1; 0, 1, 0 ], y = [1, 1, 0]$, solve for $x$ such that $Ax = y$. Both produce a solution using the inverse function on $A$, as in $x = A^{-1}y$ , yet only the first gives me back $y$ when I plug $x$ back into $Ax$, and both execute without warning.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the example. I think Carlo's answer explains very well what is going on with the problem! Here just a quick explanation of why everybody first thought what you did is impossible. It is a language thing. The terminology $A^{-1}$ is only used when $A$ is a square matrix and $A^{-1}$ is both the left inverse and the right inverse of $A$. In case $A$ is non-square and only has left inverse but no right inverse then I believe there is no agreed upon notation to denote this left inverse. Hence people thought you were talking about square matrices and found something impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an invertible $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with entries in a field $k.$ We claim that the $n \times n$ matrix $B$ such that $AB = I_{n \times n} = BA$ (where $I_{n \times n}$ is the $n \times n$ matrix with $1$s on the diagonal and $0$s elsewhere) is unique.

**Proof.** We will assume that there exists another $n \times n$ matrix $C$ such that $AC = I_{n \times n} = CA.$ Using the associativity of matrix multiplication, we have that $B = BI_{n \times n} = B(AC) = (BA)C = I_{n \times n}C = C.$ QED.

Consequently, we can designate *the* matrix inverse $B = A^{-1}$ of $A.$ Unfortunately, if you are dealing with an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ with entries in the field $k$ for distinct $m$ and $n,$ then $A$ might have a left-inverse $L$ such that $LA = I_{n \times n}$ or a right-inverse $R$ such that $AR = I_{m \times m}$ or neither [but *not* both](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2218118/are-there-non-square-matrices-that-are-both-left-and-right-invertible).

Consider the $3 \times 2$ matrix in your example $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Observe that this matrix cannot (by the linked post) have a right-inverse; however, it does have a left-inverse $$L = \begin{pmatrix} \frac 1 2 & 0 & \frac 1 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Ultimately, if we wish to solve $A \mathbf x = \mathbf y,$ we may apply $L$ on the left to obtain $\mathbf x = I_{2 \times 2} \mathbf x = (LA) \mathbf x = L(A \mathbf x) = L \mathbf y;$ however, we cannot conclude from this that $\mathbf x = L \mathbf y$ yields $A \mathbf x = \mathbf y$ because $L$ cannot be both a left- and right-inverse of $A.$

One more comment: the range of $A$ is $\operatorname{span}_k \{\langle 1, 0, 1 \rangle, \langle 0, 1, 0 \rangle \}$ since we have that $$A \mathbf x = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} = \langle a, b, a \rangle = \langle a, 0, a \rangle + \langle 0, b, 0 \rangle  = a \langle 1, 0, 1 \rangle + b \langle 0, 1, 0 \rangle.$$ Consequently, the vector $\mathbf y = \langle 1, 1, 0 \rangle$ is not in the range of $A,$ i.e., the equation $A \mathbf x = \mathbf y$ has no solution.

Comment: very insightful, thank you Carlo

Answer (score 0):

Took me some time to figure this out.
Basically, you can think as matrix as a linear operation. It is a function that maps numbers to numbers. You can think of the inverse as the 'undo' operation of this matrix. This also means you can't lose information (when operating in the linear space (no non-linear operations))

Lets say your original number is 3, and matrix is 5.
$$3 * 5 = 15$$
Inverse of 5 is $1/5$.

$$15 * 1/5 = 3$$
You just undo what you did.
In other words, given the results (15) and the inverse ($1/5$), you can re-construct the original number of 3.

However, a non-invertible matrix is 0.

$$3 * 0 = 0$$ (you have lost information)
There is no inverse for 0, 1/0 is impossible.
Hence, given the results (0) and no inverse, it is impossible to get back to the original number of 3.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).